# Why the total work to move a spring from point A to B equals the integral of all forces needed to hold it balance at every point between A and B?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, spring, elasticity

I'm reading a Calculus book that mentions the *Hooke’s Law for Springs* that says the force needed to hold a spring at $x$ cm from it normal position is: $F = kx$, where $k$ is a constant.

I can understand that formula but what I'm struggle to grasp is the formula to calculate the *work* needed to move the spring's movable endpoint from point A to point B equals to the integral of all forces needed to hold it balance at every point between A  and B. Or, in symbols:

$$ W = \int_a^b kxdx$$

Where a and be denote the signed position of the spring's movable endpoint at A and B.

UPDATE: I can't relate the "stationary" forces needed to "hold" a spring at particular points to the SUMMATION of those "holding" forces becomes the work needed to MOVE the endpoint. Why they equals each other, one type of force is applied at stationary positions and the other is on the movement.

Comment: (a) What don't you understand about the formula? (b) My unsolicited advice for you if you are learning this for the first time: don't try to interpret the definition of work. Just take it as a given. The real significance of work is that it is related to kinetic energy via the work energy theorem, and to potential energy for conservative forces. There are a lot of different definitions you need to absorb before you can see the whole picture. Sometimes courses teach things in an efficient but not always transparent way.

Comment: @Andrew I can't relate the "static" forces needed to "hold" a spring at particular points to the SUMMATION of those "static holding" forces becomes the work needed to MOVE the endpoint. Why they equals each other, one is static and one is to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume a massless spring and $F=kx$ where $F$ is the force applied to the spring and $x$ is the extension of the spring.

The graph of applied force against extension is a straight line with gradient $k$, the spring constant, as shown in blue.

[image]

The spring is extended by $x$ using an external force which increases from $0$ to $F$ and then stops increasing with the applied force $F$ being kept constant.
Whilst extending the spring from $0$ to $x$ the average force applied is $F/2$ and the work done by the external force is $F/2\cdot x$.

The spring is now extended by and extra $x$ using an external force which increases from $F$ to $2F$ and then stops increasing.
Whilst extending the spring from $x$ to $2x$ the average force applied is $3F/2$ and the work done by the external force is $3F/2\cdot x$.

The spring is again extended by and extra $x$ using an external force which increases from $2F$ to $3F$ and then stops increasing.
Whilst extending the spring from $2x$ to $3x$ the average force applied is $5F/2$ and the work done by the external force is $5F/2\cdot x$.

Thus the total work done by the external force in extending the spring from $0$ to $3 x$ is

$F/2\cdot x + 3F/2\cdot x +5F/2\cdot x = \frac 12 9Fx = \frac 12 k (3x)^2$ because $F=kx$.

All the integration does is to sum the work done for those infinitesimally small pull/hold/pull more/hold/pull more/ . . . .  motions.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, I got difficulty selecting which answer to accept. BowlOfRed explicitly pointed out some conditions under which the formula is no longer accurate, for example, the forces to accelerate the spring. Is that correct? I understand the math part but not the physics part.

Comment: I starting by stating that I had assumed a massless ideal spring just to make it easier to answer your question.in terms of apply force, spring extends, work done; apply larger force, spring extends further, more work done; apply even larger force, spring extends even further, even more work done, etc.  I did not think complicating matters would material help answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

When people ask you for the work to perform an action, they usually are asking you implicity for the minimum work required to perform that action. Because the force needed to hold the spring is $kx$ (seeing as the restoring force is $-kx$), then what they're asking you is: what is the minimal ammount of work you need to use to move the endpoint from $A$ to $B$? Which is the same as saying: make no effort to accelerate it further than it needs to; just displace it at constant velocity (seeing as the total force on the spring will then be zero).

This is a general pattern. In electrostatics you will also define the work needed to mount a point charge $q$ in some configuration of electric field $E$ as $$W=\int -qE\cdot dl$$
for example. Or perhaps more familiarly, the work required to lift an object in a uniform gravitational field $$W=\int mg \cdot dl$$ seeing as the force pulling it down is $$-mg$$

Comment: @Entrudo thanks for your answer, I've added some additional information to the question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't relate the "stationary" forces needed to "hold" a spring at particular points to the SUMMATION of those "holding" forces becomes the work needed to MOVE the endpoint.

For a "light" spring, there is no difference.   In the limit that the spring has almost zero mass, (or that we are moving the spring somewhat slowly), then the forces to accelerate the spring are negligible and we can ignore them.

The only forces that remain are the spring force from displacement.  So that is the only force that is summed in the equation.

The more massive the spring, or the more quickly you try to move the spring, the less accurate this equation is.  Some work will go into kinetic energy for the spring as well.